# How to iterate through array as item is added in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I used `ng-repeat` to loop through array made in controller. The problem is, instead of showing each value in a new row, it shows all of the array values in every row, like below:

[image]

The html code looks like this:

```
<div ng-model="wrapper_div" id="wrapper">
    <input type="button" value="Update Data"
    ng-click="updateData()" />
    <ul ng-repeat="x in data">
        <li>{{data}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
var answers = [];
function updateData(data) {

    var scope = angular.element($("#wrapper")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){

        answers.push(data);
        scope.data = answers;
    });
}
```

The expected result should look like:

```
9
6
7
```

And NOT this:

```
9,6,7
9,6,7
9,6,7
```

Comment: you used `{{data}}` in `<li></li>` tag. You should use `{{x}}` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are displaying `data` not `x` , data is an array , so complete array is displayed three time , instead display `{{x}}` try

```
<ul ng-repeat = "x in data"><li>{{x}}</li></ul>
```

Comment: oh yes, that's correct. Now shows as expected. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to move your ng-repeat to the **li** tag, not the **ul**. and in the expression, use x and not data, which is why you are getting the whole array printed every time. so your html should look something like :

```
<div ng-model = "wrapper_div" id="wrapper">
    <input type="button" value="Update Data" ng-click="updateData()"/>
    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat = "x in data">{{x}}</li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```